# Postgresql Full Text Searching : Strange behavior of AND operator

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

So, I have a PostgreSQL datable with a table *documents*

```
id|fullname
```

I added a tsv column and update the table with an index:

```
 UPDATE documents SET tsv = setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(fullname,'')), 'A');
```

But, when I do this query :

```
SELECT id, fullname, tsv
FROM documents
WHERE (tsv @@ to_tsquery('will & smith'))
```

In the results, there are rows with only *smith* and not *will* **and** *smith*.
Like this one :

```
  id    |   fullname   |       tsv
1779471 | gloria smith | gloria':1A 'smith':2A
```

This behavior seems more like an **or** operator than an **and**.

Do you have an idea why the **&** operator does not work well ?

Comment: `will` is a [stop word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-STOPWORDS) in the `english` dictionary, i.e. `SELECT to_tsvector('english','Will Smith')` *will* ;) give you `'smith':2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `simple` regconfig in your ts functions:

```
select
  *
from documents
where
  to_tsvector('simple', fullname) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'will & smith');
```

Working example here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8f950/1